# How to Call the one php page content and display it another php page using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have index page, in that i have 2 button "Staff Details" and "Student Detalis"
When i click "Staff Details" , the content of "staffDetails.php" should display in index.php

Similarly, "STudent details" also

### Ajax Function:

```
function search1()
    {       $.ajax({
                    Type:'GET',
                    url:'StaffDetails.php',
                    success:function(html)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("StaffDetails").innerHTML=html;
                    },
                })
    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: you have incorrect syntax...so there's no semicolon at the end of the ajax call. 
are index.php and staffdetails.php at the same directory level? instead of document.getElementById use : $("#StaffDetails").html(html);

Comment: Why don't you just use [`$.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) then?

Answer (score -1):

here is a complete ajax function use like this and help full for you in future

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function search1(){
$.ajax({  

  type: "POST",  
  url:"StaffDetails.php",  

  beforeSend: function()
  {
  },
  success: function(resp)
  {  

    $("#StaffDetails").html(resp);

  }, 

  complete: function()
  {
  },

  error: function(e)
  {  
  alert('Error: ' + e);  
  }  
  }); 
}

function search2(){
 $.ajax({  

  type: "POST",  
  url:"StudentDetails.php",  

  beforeSend: function()
  {
  },
  success: function(resp)
  {  

    $("#StudentDetails").html(resp);

  }, 

  complete: function()
  {
  },

  error: function(e)
  {  
    alert('Error: ' + e);  
  }  
}); 
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Staff Details" onclick="search1()" />
<input type="button" value="Student Details" onclick="search2()" />
<div id="StaffDetails">
</div>
<div id="StudentDetails">
</div>
</body>
```

here is full ajax working and tested example hope no question left now.
Thanks!

Comment: Please give an explanation of how to use it, why it should work, any pitfalls one needs to be aware of, etc. Links to further documentation is also a good thing.

Comment: <?php
$student_query="select * from schl_staffdetails";
$list_of_staff=mysql_query($student_query);
?>
<tr><td><table align="center" border="2"></tr><?php while($row_values=mysql_fetch_array($list_of_staff)) { ?><tr>     <td><input type="radio" name="selectSTUDENT"/></td><?php /*?><td style="font-size:20px;color:#0066FF" align="center"><b><?php echo $row_values['S_AdmissionID']?></td><?php */?><td><?php echo $row_values['Staff_Name']?></td><td><?php echo $row_values['Staff_Qualification']?></td><td><?php echo $row_values['Staff_Gender']?></td>
</tr><?php }?></table></td></tr>